# Azure AD B2C KMSI (Keep Me Signed In) does not keep me signed in

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I am a bit confused about what I've implemented so far should or should not work. (I've also read [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-kmsi-custom) but I am not sure how up to date is, things are changing week by week)

**Context**

I am implementing a web site where I utilize AD B2C for authentication. (using out of the box ASP.NET Core 3 template) **All works except KMSI**.

I've created the User flows (policies) as the pictures show (see below) The KMSI checkbox is there, but no effect.

**Question**

What am I missing? Should this work out of the box, or should I upload a custom policy XML, if yes then why is the KMSI checkbox in this built in template, using the configured userflow?

**What I've done so far**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The official doc is for custom policy. May I know if your sign-up/sign-in policy is bult-in policy or custom policy?

Comment: Thanks for asking: it is a built in policy I did nothing else on Azure side what is in the three pictures. My doubt also comes from that the doc  describes a custom policy. I even downloaded my built in policy’s XML, but no similar parts in it what is described in the doc

Answer (score 3):

At the moment Keep me sign in is not supported in basic user flows. Please use Page Layout Version 1.0.0 for Unified sign up or sign in page, so the KMSI check box will not appear.

Comment: Any changes on KMSI support in built in user flows?

Comment: Also interested in knowing this.